# Kotlin: Why Array and ArrayList are not emptied before a rerun?

Tags: android, kotlin, initialization, global-variables

My scientific app is fully dynamic and there is only one activity, no fragment or intent.

In some situations, I need to finish the app completely.

So I run

```
(this as Activity).finishAndRemoveTask()
```

It works smoothly since `Lollipop (Android 5.0), version 21`.
Apparently, no app traces or services remains in the memory.

However, I've found a huge problem.

I have some global array or array list (I didn't see other variables).
that remains intact with a new rerun, even a I have a declaration
that empties that variables. It doesn't happen with a rerun via debugger,
should be a new rerun from cell phone.

Below I show a schematic example. I declare in one .kt file, outside any class or function.

```
class DispFu(
  var id: Int = 0,    
  var isKeyl:Boolean=false, 
}
var vDispFu = arrayListOf<DispFu>()
```

After, I populate `vDispFu` inside onCreate processing and reach 134 items.

To prove it, I've recorded a file on my phone inside my activity onCreate processing, before exit the program.

```
fun now():String{
  var hora = LocalTime.now()
  return "${hora.hour}:${hora.minute}:${hora.second}"
}

var fileDep:File = createOrGetFile(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory
  (Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),"DepCalc","") // File for debugging
fileDep.appendText("${now()} -> vDispFu size is ${vDispFu.size}\n")
```

Below there are 2 runs: the first run (inside debugger) and a independent rerun. Here is the file content:

```
11:3:2 -> vDispFu size is 0
11:3:18 -> vDispFu size is 134
```

I know that `global variables` are not recommended, but I just wanted to understand what is going on. It doesn't make sense to me.

If someone could give me some clue about what is happening and give me some alternative strategy, it would be great!

Obviously, for practical reasons, the solution could not involve completely reformulating the program, which has almost 40 thousand lines...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finishing an Activity doesn't shut down your entire Application or VM, so all global variables continue to stay in memory. When you rerun your application with the debugger, it actually restarts the VM, which is why you're seeing it get cleared in that case.

`System.exit()` is not an ideal solution since it restarts your VM process. There will be extra churn to do that. It's really intended for abnormal unrecoverable errors. Not necessarily a problem in your particular case.

The more proper way to handle this would be to put your top-level data in a singleton and clear it manually when you are finishing the Activity.

Comment: Ok, but if starting the VM is so expensive, as you explain that when I close the app dragging it to the right (or left) after `app overview` button, the Android doesn't present this reported problem, i.e, global variable are empty again, i.e., it forces the VM to restart if I re-run  the application (as you said). The only thing that I do is doing it inside the app...

Comment: When you close the app via the task switcher, it actually shuts down the whole application and does not restart it. The purpose of this feature is to allow users to force an app to stop running, maybe because it got into some unrecoverable locked-up state or because they want it to stop running any services. In practice, it is probably used more frequently by anal retentive users that don't want to leave anything in an open state. `System.exit()` shuts your app down and restarts it (but not the Activity or task you were running). In practice this isn't a big deal, especially on modern devices.

Comment: Yes, but it is common in several hours of use that I have about 15 applications open. It is common for me to want to close them, if only to clean the whole thing.

Comment: There must be many users with the problem you mentioned :), because both Apple and Google give you easy access to this feature of terminating applications.

Comment: In addition, having 10 or 15 active tasks makes switching between tasks more difficult, just as having 50 tabs open in the browser starts to make navigation difficult. Besides, there is a legion of people who have more than limited RAM in their devices.

Comment: "if only to clean the whole thing" That's what I was saying most people probably use it for, the psychological feeling of cleanliness, or like you said, so you can find things faster in the task switcher. RAM isn't a concern because Android force-closes apps as necessary to recover RAM. There is a downside to closing apps when you don't need to: you have to wait for them to be loaded again when you go back to them. The problem I mentioned is common. Some very popular apps occasionally get stuck in some sort of loop, or a blank page due to some bugs.

Comment: This is the whole reason that by design, Android and iOS apps have no obvious way to "quit" them. Unlike on Windows, it reduces performance rather than improving it. It's the reason Android apps have to be designed to handle being closed at any moment they are not on-screen.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem:

Sometimes, it is incredible how the effort to externalize a problem sometimes helps to solve it ....

The below procedure to quit completely an app:

```
(this as Activity).finishAndRemoveTask()
```

It's not enough, despite all the posts about it on `Stack Overflow` that advocate this strategy.

It's necessary includes other command:

```
(this as Activity).finishAndRemoveTask()
System.exit(0)
```

Now:

```
11:26:25 -> vDispFu size is 0
11:27:1 -> vDispFu size is 0
```